# Получить кучу данных из строки

Tags: php, json

Есть ответ,который выдал сервер при *GET* запросе:

> {"response":{"count":494080,"items":[{"id":2328,"first_name":"Дмитрий","last_name":"Шпионъ","sex":2},{"id":2489,"first_name":"Виктория","last_name":"Дикарева","sex":1},{"id":2846,"first_name":"Алексей","last_name":"Павлович","sex":2},{"id":3110,"first_name":"Вероника","last_name":"Александрова","sex":1,"hidden":1},{"id":3307,"first_name":"Александр","last_name":"Смирнов","sex":2,"hidden":1},{"id":4041,"first_name":"Nikolay","last_name":"Nikolaevich","sex":2},
>
> ***etc***...

Необходимо извлечь такие данные как *id,first_name,last_name,etc*
Я думаю что самым лучшим вариантом будет использование регулярок.Если да,то помогите составить выражение.

Comment: Не нужны вам регулярки, это json строка. Используйте json_decode().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым лучшим будет использование функций для работы с JSON, например json_decode.

Comment: Не работает:( `error_reporting(E_ALL);
$str = '{"response":{"count":493677,"items":      [{"id":2328,"first_name":"Дмитрий","last_name":"Шпионъ","sex":2},                                  {"id":2489,"first_name":"Виктория","last_name":"Дикарева","sex":1}}';var_dump(json_decode($str));`

Comment: Конечно не работает, закрывающую скобку не передали.

Comment: Спасибо.Только вот извлечь обычным способом начинку что-то не получается.То что получил(немного обрезал) `stdClass Object ( [response] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 318513705 [first_name] => Василий [last_name] => Чебуркин ) ) )` .Пытаюсь обратится как-то вроде `$arr[0]` пишет ошибку `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in E:\OpenServer\domains\Parser\index.php on line 13` .С таким еще не сталкивался

Comment: Читайте документацию по PHP и ищите примеры работы с json_decode.